# vim replace search text by manipulated search text

Tags: vim, regular-expression

This is a very simplified version of my problem. Suppose I have a text file containing several places the code 20091a or 20092a or 20093a. I'm wishing to surround all this code by the text `<code></code>`. So the resulting strings above would be like `<code>20091a</code>` or `<code>20092a</code>` or `<code>20093a</code>`.

So how do I replace the search text with text containing the search text? Is there any variable which holds the search text so that I could use something like `:%s/2009.a/<code>$SEARCH_TEXT<\/div>`?

Comment: If the original codes are part of an XML file, the more generic way is not to use `vi` and parse the XML and then insert the text in a newly created node anywhere where you found it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `\0` or `&` in the replacement as in

```
:%s/2009.a/ \0 /gc
:%s/2009.a/ & /gc
```